# System Monitor Resources Customisation

Tags: server, system-monitor

Im currently usig ubuntu as a server, and i use gnome-system-monitor to track (visually) how much cpu load is being consumed, however, I only see the last 60 seconds of usage.

Is there a way to set the gnome-system-monitor to remember the last 300 seconds (or some other value)?

Thanks,

Comment: You can change the update interval to 5 seconds (*Edit* → *Preferences*), but that's probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: @htorque correct, It is not the granularity, of the graphs, but their timespan that i am looking to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program `sar` or `atsar` also might be helpful. You can start them in a terminal or shell. The option `-u` shows information about CPU. The last the options are the time between updates and the number of data points you'd like to have.

```
atsar -u 15 9999999
21:06:20  cpu %usr  %sys  %nice  %idle                          _cpu_
21:06:35  all    5     2      0     93
21:06:48  all   48     4      0     49
21:07:03  all   59     3      0     37
21:07:18  all   65     4      0     31
21:07:33  all   53     4      0     42
21:07:48  all    8     2      0     90
21:08:03  all    5     1      0     94
```

Depending on your font size and the size of your terminal you'll see the last 300 seconds (20 measurements) of your CPU life.

Answer (score 1):

Not within `gnome-system-monitor`, no and it's actually an ***awful*** tool for monitoring resources long-term because it consumed so much CPU.

I suggest you take a look at `munin`. It's a simple little tool for monitoring resources on a server. It creates graphs (not as pretty System Monitor) and logs things over a long time. It generates static HTML files on a periodic basis (every 5 minutes, IIRC) which you can either browse locally or you can serve via Apache (et al) so you can view the stats over the network.

You can see more about munin in [another answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/9129/449).

Comment: munin seems to be a solution that is over the top for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful tool is `dstat`. It is quite similar to `atsar`, but is quite more powerful. If you want to get CPU information, enter:

```
dstat -c 

----total-cpu-usage----
usr sys idl wai hiq siq
 17   3  78   2   0   1
  7   2  88   3   0   0
  6   2  89   2   0   0
  5   2  91   2   0   0
 15   3  79   3   0   0
 17   3  75   5   0   0
 21   3  73   3   0   0
```

`dstat` has colored output. So you can see quite easily if there is too much load or any other problem.