# How to install icinga on Ubuntu 12.04 & Monitor remote host?

Tags: monitor, webserver

How to install latest icinga & icinga-web  on Ubuntu Server 12.04 & How to monitor remote hosts ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Installing the neccessary software

Lets start with installing dbconfig-common. This package is used during the installation of the remaining software to ask the user questions about database access

```
apt-get install dbconfig-common
```

Now install the Icinga and Iciga-Idoutils packages, this should install a whole lot of dependencies as well

```
apt-get install python-software-properties 
add-apt-repository ppa:formorer/icinga
apt-get update
```

#### Installing icinga

```
apt-get install icinga icinga-idoutils mysql-server libdbd-mysql mysql-client
```

During the installation you’ll need to provide parameters for **Postfix** choose the default **Internet site** and the **password of your MySQL root user**. Be sure to provide valid answers because the information will be written to several files and changing them afterwards is annoying.

Now the first part is done and you should already be able to access your Icinga installation at http://yourhostname.com/icinga with the username ‘icingaadmin’ and the password you entered during installation.

### Configuring idoutils and ido2db

To enable ido2db, edit **/etc/default/icinga** and set **IDO2DB to ‘yes’** .

**BUG**  if you are installing icinga 1.7.1 ++ you need to create a file manually

```
    cd /etc/icinga/modules
    nano idoutils.cfg
```

Now paste the following lines .

```
define module{
        module_name     idomod
        module_type     neb
        path            /usr/lib/icinga/idomod.so
        args            config_file=/etc/icinga/idomod.cfg
        }
```

For Safe Side also do

```
ln -s /usr/lib/icinga/idomod.so /usr/sbin/
```

### UPDATED

```
nano /etc/default/icinga
```

Edit IDO2DB=no to yes

```
IDO2DB=yes
```

And Run

```
/etc/init.d/ido2db start
/etc/init.d/icinga restart
```

**look in /var/log/syslog**

> **Configuring Icinga to send email**

**Edit**

nano /etc/icinga/objects/contacts_icinga.cfg

**Change**

```
root@localhost to your-email-address
```

### Icinga-Web

```
add-apt-repository ppa:formorer/icinga-web
apt-get update
apt-get install icinga-web
```

http://yourhostname.com/icinga-web

#### Done

### Monitoring Remote Host From Your Server

> The only think you need to install on remote server is nrpe & nagios-plugins

In this example my remote host is a freeBSD server which i want to monitor remotely

```
pkg_add -r nagios-plugins nrpe
```

In the `/etc/rc.conf` file, add a line to enable the nrpe2 daemon.

```
nrpe2_enable="YES"
```

#### Configuration

In the `/usr/local/etc` directory, copy the `nrpe.cfg-sample` file to a file named `nrpe.cfg`. Use the `chmod u+x nrpe.cfg` command to add write permissions for the root user.

Open the file in a text editor, and look for the `allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1` line. points to the address of your Nagios server.

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,icinga-server-ip
```

Start the NRPE daemon.

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nrpe2 start
```

### Now back to Icinga Server

```
cd /etc/icinga/objects
```

Edit

```
nano localhost_icinga.cfg


define host{
        use                     generic-host            ; Name of host template to use
        host_name               localhost
        alias                   localhost
        address                 127.0.0.1
        }
```

#### Add another host under it. FreeBSD Server

```
define host{
        use                     generic-host            ; Name of host template to use
        host_name               FreeBSD
        alias                   FreeBSD
        address                 ip-address-of-FreeBSD-server
        }
```

> Now at every service define your host seperated by " , " localhost,FreeBSD

host_name      localhost,FreeBSD ; 2 hostname may be more depend of host you define

#### Example For One Service

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost,FreeBSD
        service_description             Disk Space
        check_command                   check_all_disks!20%!10%
        }
```

#### Now Edit  hostgroups_icinga.cfg for monitoring HTTP & SSH

```
nano hostgroups_icinga.cfg

define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name  http-servers
                alias           HTTP servers
                members         localhost,FreeBSD 
        }

# A list of your ssh-accessible servers
define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name  ssh-servers
                alias           SSH servers
                members         localhost,FreeBSD
        }
```

#### Now restart icinga

```
/etc/init.d/icinga restart
```

Now go to http://yourhostname.com/icinga OR http://yourhostname.com/icinga-web monitor your remote host from **Ubuntu**

#### Help

<s>http://www.meier.ws/2012/02/icinga-1-6-as-a-monitoring-solution-on-ubuntu-12-04-part-1-installation/</s> <sup>Page not found | Homepage von Michael Meier. [Way Back Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120914004340/http://www.meier.ws/2012/02/icinga-1-6-as-a-monitoring-solution-on-ubuntu-12-04-part-1-installation)</sup>

[Installing NRPE on FreeBSD 9.0](http://beginlinux.com/server/nagios/installing-nrpe-on-freebsd-90)

[Setting up Icinga with IDOUtils on Ubuntu - HowTos - Icinga Wiki](https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Setting+up+Icinga+with+IDOUtils+on+Ubuntu)

### Update

> **BUG** icinga is not sending emails .
>
> Edit your /ets/hosts file & if should look like this

```
127.0.0.1  localhost xxxx-host-xxx 
xxx.xx.xx  localhost xxxx-host-xxx FreeBSD
```

Comment: Helped me a lot, thanks! Especially the bug part about ``idoutils.cfg``. Still present and not mentioned in any *getting started* guide. Sigh.

Comment: I don't think your ``check_all_disks`` command will work remotely as you don't use ``check_nrpe`` anywhere I don't see how it can gather the data from remote. It will use the data of localhost and publish it for the remote - not good. See also [this page](http://docs.icinga.org/1.7/en/nrpe.html).