# Is there in ubuntu repository monitoring alternative to nagios?

Tags: log, monitoring, network-monitoring

I would like to run some kind of service monitoring for my server and few other servers/services. Basically I want to monitor availability and send mail, when avail. is bad. Is there any simple alternative to nagios in Ubuntu repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ICINGA**, It has all the option you have asked for.

Check the installation [How to install icinga on Ubuntu 12.04 & Monitor remote host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169033/how-to-install-icinga-on-ubuntu-12-04-monitor-remote-host/169034#169034)

---

Just keep in mind install MySQL before installing it. Some time it conflict when installing.

```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server libdbd-mysql mysql-client
```